# Creating subset matrix from bigger matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, subset

I have a big matrix (i.e 303*32). I want to create take out some columns and make a new matrix in R. I am unable to find any solution. Any help would be appreciated.

```
ads # Matrix of 303*32
new_mat <- matrix(c("speed","gaps","time")) # speed, gaps and times are names of cols which I am trying to exclude.
```

By using this code i am only getting cols and rows name .

Answer (score 2):

If you want to **exclude** columns by name, you need something like:

```
new_mat <- ads[, !colnames(ads) %in% c("speed","gaps","time")]
```

Comment: I've always been partial to `ads[, -match(c("speed","gaps","time"), colnames(ads))]` as it will error out if you ask for a variable that doesn't exist.

Comment: @thelatemail I think this won't work if you have columns with the same names. I know it's bad but it could happen.